# How can I convert a Set to an Array in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, set, typescript1.8

How can I convert a Set (eg, {2,4,6}) to an Array [2, 4, 6] in TypeScript without writing a loop explicitly ?

I have tried those following ways, all of them work in JavaScript but none of them work on TypeScript

```
[...set] // ERR: "Type 'Set<{}>' is not an array type" in typescript

Array.from(set) // ERR: Property 'from' does not exist on type 'ArrayConstructor'
```

Comment: what target are you compiling to? Both Set and Array.from were added in ES6 and are not available when compiling to ES5. If you want to use them you can try using core.js to get polyfils for them.

Comment: @toskv You are right, it worked when I change target option to 'ES6', my current target is 'ES5'

Comment: I'm having a possibly related issue now, `Type 'Set<string>' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators. ts(2569)`. [mayan anger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48264936/705296) solved it for me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Fix

- Use tsconfig.json with `"lib": ["es6"]`

## More

- Google `lib` option.
- I wrote some docs too : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html#lib-option

Comment: The doc link is invalid.

Answer (score 220):

You also can do

```
Array.from(my_set.values());
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer

Comment: Well, somehow this didn't work for me... my Set is made of strings surrounded by { } so i don't know what is wrong

Answer (score 40):

if you declare your set this way:

```
const mySet = new Set<string>();
```

you will be able to easily use:

```
let myArray = Array.from( mySet );
```

Answer (score 6):

or simply

```
const mySet = new Set<string>();
mySet.add(1);
mySet.add(2);
console.log([...mySet.values()]);
```

Answer (score 4):

@basarat's answer wasn't sufficient in my case: I couldn't use the spread operator despite having `esnext` in my `lib` array.

To correctly enable using the spread operator on sets and other ES2015 iterables, I had to enable the `downlevelIteration` compiler option.

Here's how to set it via `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "downlevelIteration": true
  }
}
```

You will find a more detailed explanation of this flag in the [TS documentation page about compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html#compiler-options).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using the `!` post-fix expression operator to assert that its operand is non-null and non-undefined.

> You'll find further information in [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)

You can use the spread operator to convert a Set into an Array:

```
const mySet = new Set(['h','j','l','l']);
console.log([...mySet!])
```